# Magnific Popup: How to modify showCloseBtn and closeOnBgClick while open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Is there a way to edit an open instance of a [magnific popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)? In one state I want the popup to be closable, and in another state I want to block user from closing. It seems these options are only available for intilialisation:

```
$('.target-div').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: "inline",
    closeOnBgClick: true,
    showCloseBtn: true,
    gallery: {
        enabled: false
}})
```

Then, while the popup is open, I want to block accidental closing and take away the X button.

```
$('.target-div').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: "inline",
    closeOnBgClick: false,
    showCloseBtn: false,
    gallery: {
        enabled: false
}})
```

Comment: The state is in same DOM or the state in only for logged in user, provide some more info

Comment: State is in same DOM, for same user. I swap out target-div to a form, where I do not want them to close accidentally. (app is django, and I swap div using htmx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MagnificPopup stores a single instance in the jQuery var (`$.magnificPopup`), which controls the popup's behavior in the DOM. It's actually really easy to update the background click behavior by changing a single setting.

```
$.magnificPopup.instance.st.closeOnBgClick = false
```

Internally, MFP uses $.detach() and $.append() to control the presence of the close button. To remove it, we can duplicate the way it works in `_close()` by calling:

```
$.magnificPopup.instance.currTemplate.closeBtn.detach()
```

Re-adding it is a bit more difficult because the library uses a private function called `_getCloseBtn()` to generate the element. Fortunately we can just re-append it from the same place we removed it.

```
$.magnificPopup.instance.content.append($.magnificPopup.instance.currTemplate.closeBtn)
```

Source: https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/blob/c8f6b8549ebff2306c5f1179c9d112308185fe2c/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js

Demo page used for testing: https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: wow, you really know MFP - thank you so much! This worked exactly as you said it would.